# Is there a jQuery exit functionality?

Tags: jquery

I have a custom function called addItem() that has each() function inside it. When a certain condition is met, I need to exit from the addItem() function. I cannot use `return` as it only exits from the each() function and still runs the rest of the code inside the main function. I tried `exit` and it seems to work perfectly. I just don't know if using `exit` is the right way to do this 'cause I haven't seen `exit` used much.

Here is my code:

```
var addItem = function (position) {
    $(position + ' .item_div').each(function() {
        if($(this).find('.item').val() == '') {
            alert('Cannot be empty');
            exit;  // exit from addItem() function
                   // return does not work
        }
    });
    ...........
    ...........
    rest of the code here... this gets executed ONLY if each() fails...
    ...........
    ...........
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use return false to break [.each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) loop.

> You can stop the loop from within the callback function by returning false.

```
var addItem = function (position) {
    var valid = true;
    $(position + ' .item_div').each(function() {
        if($(this).find('.item').val() == '') {
            alert('Cannot be empty');
            valid = false;
            return false;
        }
    });

    if(!valid) {
        return;
    }
    ...........
    ...........
    rest of the code here... this gets executed ONLY if each() fails...
    ...........
    ...........
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I did but it is still executing the rest of the code even after exiting from each() function. I have no idea what's going on. Would you know if using `exit` is a bad practice? It seems to work very well in my case.

Comment: Yes I was thinking of doing that anyway. That works. Thanks. I'm still not sure if `exit` is still a valid option. Nobody seemed to be able to tell me. If you happen to figure it out, do let me know.

Comment: @user1448031 I don't think, never seen it before or any document to support the usage of it

Answer (score 0):

According to docs. yes. you need to `return false;` in the loop   [Break loop](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.each)

```
$('.someclass').each(function() {

    if (someConditionMet)
        return false;
});
```

Comment: I already tried `return false` but it does not work. It only exits the each() function but still runs the rest of the code. Is it because of the `alert()` that for some reason making it a bit difficult? But I don't think so.... `exit` seems to work perfect. Do you know if `exit` is deprecated or is not a good practice?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using break.
The break statement "jumps out" of a loop.

Or you can create label and use goto to jump to that label.

Comment: Try using goto.
create a label and then use goto to jump there.

Comment: @Dev are u seriously suggesting goto ?http://xkcd.com/292/   bad answer and bad suggestion .

Comment: @Dev Perhaps `exit` is a lot better than using goto :)